# Remove first character if match from string

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to check, string start with `+` sign and if it is then remove the `+` sign from the string like `+B` to `B`. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
strData = IIf(InStr(1, strData, "+") = 1, Mid(strData, 2), strData)
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you so much.